# Remote Desktop Connection for a Guest Account for Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7

How do I set up a remote desktop connection for a guest account on my home computer with Windows 7 Professional?

Answer (score 3):

You must both allow remote connections to your home computer and grant the guest account RDP access to the computer.

**To Allow Remote Connections**

1. Right-click on Computer -> Properties -> Remote Settings and select one of the two options to allow remote connections

**To Grant the Guest Account RDP Access**

2. Open the Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Computer Management
3. Under 'Local Users and Groups' -> 'Groups', right-click the Remote Desktop Users group and select 'Add to Group'
4. Click 'Add'. Enter 'Guest' into the account name, choose 'Check Name', OK.